# What does RWM mean?

Tags: microprocessor, computers, computer-architecture

I'm studying computer hardware and the acronym "RWM" appears, so I wonder what it means? It has to do with LOADs and STOREs of instructions.

[image]

Comment: In this context I would expect this to be about read / write memory, i.e. the unit which handles memory loads and stores within the microarchitecture. The diagram is not so clear on where the instruction decoding is done, but without memory accesses the whole pipeline would be fairly limited (only register accesses possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction.
I made the unfortunate dyslexic mistake of reading the three letter abbreviation as RMW when it was RWM. In the context of the block diagram of the original question I would have to agree that -

RWM means "Read - Write - Memory" as in an operational sequence.

I'll leave my original comment below as it is also a very important concept in computer architecture too.

RMW means "Read - Modify - Write".

Typically this is in the context of the computer architecture that the RWM operation is designed in such way that it is an atomic sequence. This means that a register contents can be partially changed in one operation without being interrupted by an other part of the computer before the register update is complete.

Comment: If that were true then "RWM" should stand for "Read - Write - Modify".

Comment: Just for my idle curiosity, why isn't it called RMW?

Comment: Read-Modify-Write is typical referred as RMW. RWM propably means Read-Write Memory.

Comment: @Mandar -- I think you're right. Post as a separate answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: @Mandar: you are definitely correct.  It is the data memory (both readable and writable.)

Comment: Wow - I think you are correct. RMW is such a common epression at the microprocessor company where I work that my dyslexia made me see it as such. Sorry...

Comment: I think because the diagram shows not only functional blocks but the flow of execution, it does refer to memory. This RWM is in the execution phase. An instruction could be a load and store with an addressing mode. In which case two operands will go in to select the memory location: for instance a base register and a displacement register. And one result comes out: the fetched word. So the read-write-memory is like another ALU: a big lookup table with several inputs and one output.  Store instructions are not well represented in the diagram, however.

Comment: But A for effort for trying to represent sequencing in a static diagram of functional blocks.

Comment: @Kaz: In introductory computer organization books, the inputs to the data mem are usually (1) an address and (2) a data word.  That's so you can do a store operation.  If you want to do a load you provide only the address and the data word comes out the "bottom" of the memory block.  Address arithmetic requires an extra cycle (you put base and displacent operands through the ALU, put the resulting address back in a register, and then in the following cycle you do your load or store.)

Comment: Michael has updated his answer. Kaz, Wandering Logic have clear explanation in context of processor architecture. Those are more relevant answers, I think.